# WPF: How to write stream which owned by main process in thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, stream

I want to implement this function: when receive a http request, then create a new window form, and waiting for user inputing response text and write to the http response stream. The quesition is, I can not write response text to the stream in thread even I useing the Action<> delegate. Some code like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //startup web server 
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(Start));
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        var server = new HttpServer();
        try
        {
            server.EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 80);
            server.Start();
            server.RequestReceived += DataProcess;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void DataProcess(object sender, HttpRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        //create a new window in which user can input the response for the http request e.
        var pw = (PrivateWindow)Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<HttpRequestEventArgs, PrivateWindow>(CreatePrivateWindow), e);
    }

    public PrivateWindow CreatePrivateWindow(string windowKey, HttpRequestEventArgs e)      
    {
        var pw = new PrivateWindow(); 
        pw.httpRequest = e;//pass the stream to thread here.       
        windows.Add(pw);
        return pw;    
    }
}

public partial class PrivateWindow : Window
{
    private void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string messageText = new TextRange(txtWriteMessage.Document.ContentStart, txtWriteMessage.Document.ContentEnd).Text.Trim(); 
        //write the response in thread           
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<HttpRequestEventArgs, string>(WriteToStream), httpRequest, messageText);
    }
    private void WriteToStream(HttpRequestEventArgs e, string str)
    {
        //**here occurs "stream can not be written" error.** 
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(e.Response.OutputStream))
        {
            writer.Write(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i don't know the classes, but why do you want to WRITE in the response? Shouldn't you be reading what you got as a response? Again, i never used these classes so its just what i had in mind after reading your code.

Comment: Because I want to response the http request manualy.

Comment: What i mean is, you start your server; you wait for reponses; you get a reponse in your RequestReceived event, which contains what request is coming in; but then you want to write that data that you just received. I would guess the exception is thrown because the stream is readonly, because there is no reason why you should write into the response, your should read from it. What is that HttpServer control anyway, which library is it from? I don't find this class in the msdn.

Comment: In MainWindow, the response can both be read and written, and the HttpServer is a three-party dll library (https://github.com/pvginkel/NHttp).

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't write"? Do you get an error?

Comment: the stream field of "canWrite" is false.

Comment: Your way looks nice. But I wanna to konw, if the text is passed to the main window, how the DataProcess() method capture this news and write the text to the response?

Comment: I think, your write stream have been closed when your btnSendMessage_Click function is called. After calling CreatePrivateWindow function you return program to httpserver execution, so it closes the stream.