# WPF: How can I pass the text of textbox in a thread to the main window?

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a child textbox control in an chlid window form created by main window form using thread technology, and I wanna implement this function: In the child window form, when I click a button (or Enter-key-down), it pass the text to the main window form. What can I do about that?

Comment: When you say "using thread technology" do you mean that the 2 forms are running on different threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way for the *ChildWindow* to send a message back to *MainWindow*. Following example should be useful:

#### Code:

An Interface to allow "communication" between windows

```
public interface IListner
{
    void Send(String message);
}
```

MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IListner
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Send(string message)
    {
        // Read the message here.
        // If this code is called from different thread, use "Dispatcher.Invoke()"
    }

    public void OpenAnotherWindow()
    {
        // Since "MainWindow" implements "IListner", it can pass it's own instance to "ChildWindow"
        ChildWindow childWindow = new ChildWindow(this);
    }  
}
```

ChildWindow:

```
public partial class ChildWindow : Window
{
    private IListner Listner { get; set; }

    public ChildWindow(IListner listner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Listner = listner;
    }

    private void OnTextBoxTextChanged()
    {
        // This will call "Send" on "MainWindow"
        Listner.Send(TextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: decycloe, thanks for you reply. But could you help me to look up the actual problem descirbed in this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737388/wpf-how-to-write-stream-which-owned-by-main-process-in-thread

Answer (score 0):

A quick google will bring you back loads of results...

The best thing to do is probably when you create Form2 (the child) have a public method available where you can pass in an instance of Form1 (the parent) and then the same again on Form1 but pass a string rather than a instance of a form. So you would end up with something like this:

Form1 (parent):

```
private void Button1_Click_ShowChildForm(args..)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();
    frm2.GetInstance(this);
}

public void PassBack(string var)
{
    TextBox1.Text = var;
}
```

Form2 (child):

```
private static Form1 _frm1;

public void GetInstance(Form1 Frm1)
{
    this._frm1 = Frm1;
}

private void Button2_Click_Close(args...)
{
   _frm1.PassBack(this.TextBox2.Text);
   this.Close();
}
```

Something like that ^^^ should do the trick. ;)

NB. You could probably tidy it up a bit and if you really wanted to you could probably override the Show method of the Form2 to accept an instance of Form1 instead of declaring a separate method but you get the idea.

Comment: @daryal It's C#. WPF is the XML based stuff you write for the UI. The two work beautifully in sync!

Comment: good job. In fact, the case of my problem is like this: In the form1, I startup a http server using .Invoke(), and when a new http request arrives, a new form (e.g form2) is created and wait for the response(it's a field of the http request and type is stream) which require user input manually in form2's textbox and click. Using your way, it can pass the text to form1, but how can I write it to the response field of httprequest? When there are many http request arives, how can i do?

Comment: @TomJacky I can see this is going to be a little bit more tricky than I initially thought...
Can you edit your question please with the code that you have so far with the HTTP request - from there we should be able to work something out.

Comment: Thx, Govix. here is my question which submitted some days ago and describes in detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737388/wpf-how-to-write-stream-which-owned-by-main-process-in-thread